# Compute the total variation of a linear bounded functional

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure in $\mathbb R^n$, if $L:C_C^{0}(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^m) \to \mathbb R$ be a linear functional, the total variation of $L$ is defined by
$$|L|(A)= \sup \{ L(\varphi): \varphi \in C_C^{0}(A, \mathbb R^m), ||g|| \leq 1 \}$$
for open sets, and for $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ arbitrary
$$|L|(E)=\inf \{|L|(A) : E \subset A, A \hbox { open } \}$$
if $L$ is bounded then $|L|$ is a radon measure, now let $f \in L_{loc}^{1}(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^m)$ ($\int_{K} ||f|| < \infty, $ for all $K$ compact) and define
$f\mu : C_C^{0}(\mathbb R^n , \mathbb R^m) \to \mathbb R$ by
$$f\mu(\varphi)=\int_{\mathbb R^n} \langle f | \varphi \rangle d\mu$$
show that $|f\mu|=||f|| \mu$  where
$$||f||\mu(A)=\int_{A} ||f|| d\mu$$
i show that
$$|f \mu|\leq ||f|| \mu$$
but for the another inequality i have problems, i try to use the density of $C_C^{0}(\mathbb R^n)$ in $L^{1}$ but i not sure if these is the right way.
Any hint or help i willl be very grateful

Comment: Density is definitely right track, but there's a few subtleties to watch out for. 1. What function should $\varphi$ approach? 2. Is $L^1$-convergence actually enough to get what we want?

Comment: Nope i use the pass to $L^1-$convergence to convergence $\mu-$c.t.p. via subsequence, and the function that approach  is $\frac{f_i \chi_A}{||f||}$